# progress event triggering on complete event

Tags: actionscript-3, events

i was trying to load swf2 inside another swf1 and to show swf2's loading progress. after doing this ProgressEvent.PROGRESS is triggering when swf2 downloads completely. Please suggest me where to change.
i have done this as

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent; 

var myLoader = new Loader(); 
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError); 

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("swf/Set1.swf"));

function onProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
var nPercent:Number = Math.round((evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal) * 100);    
temp.text = nPercent.toString() + "%";
} 
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);  
addChild(myLoader);
} 
function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
trace("IOError loading SWF");
}
```

Comment: It's normal that it triggers, why would it not?

Comment: you should read my question once again...Progress Event is working as Complete event

Comment: the last step of progress sure is completeness, so as @BotMaster said, it's natural that the Progress event fires. Maybe you could try to be a bit more descriptive in your explanation. What exactly do you expect to be different and why?

Comment: It depends on the size of your loaded swf ! So if the size of your swf is some KB, sure it will be loaded very quickly and you will think that Progress Event is working as Complete event.

Comment: You can use a `trace()` inside your `onComplete` function and you will see that's shown just after the `100%` of your progress event hanlder.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that allows you to make that statement to start with and there's nothing in your code that could even produce what you say. There cannot be some kind of magical way for an event with a given listener (onProgress) to suddenly decide by itself to trigger another listener it has no knowledge of (onComplete). So yes I did read your question and none of what you say is even possible.

Comment: Many Thanks to all of you for your Suggestions....my file is of 1.2 MB also it is not cached on my system's temp memory...to be more explainative , my problem was that OnProgress Event was triggering just before the OnComplete Event. So the loader was not increasing (was stuck at 0%) and after few seconds it directly showed 100% . I come to know that this is a system problem...on some systems it is working correctly...